# Vectorized selection along level variable

Tags: python, python-xarray

When building a DataArray, I can conveniently select along some coordinate:

```
import xarray as xr

d = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3],
                 coords={'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
                 dims=['c'])
d.sel(c='a')
```

and even along multiple values on that coordinate:

```
d.sel(c=['a', 'b'])
```

However, this fails to work once the coordinate is part of a multi-index dimension:

```
d = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3],
                 coords={'c': ('multi_index', ['a', 'b', 'c']), 
                         'd': ('multi_index', ['x', 'y', 'z'])},
                 dims=['multi_index'])
d.sel(c='a')  # error
d.sel(c=['a', 'b'])  # error
```

with the error `ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['c'] do not exist`.
Another error message I see in trying to do this is `ValueError: Vectorized selection is not available along level variable`.
It seems like one can only select along dimensions.
This becomes difficult when a single dimension contains a lot of metadata and one would only like to select based on the values of a single metadata-coordinate.

Is there a suggested workaround other than positionally indexing things by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`swap_dims` does some workaround.

```
In [8]: d.swap_dims({'multi_index': 'c'}).sel(c=['a', 'b'])
Out[8]: 
<xarray.DataArray (c: 2)>
array([1, 2])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) <U1 'a' 'b'
    d        (c) <U1 'a' 'b'
```

where 'c' becomes dimension instead of 'multi_index'.

If you want to select based on 'c' and 'd' in random manner, the use of `MultiIndex` maybe appropriate. `set_index` does this,

```
In [12]: d.set_index(cd=['c', 'd'])
Out[12]: 
<xarray.DataArray (multi_index: 3)>
array([1, 2, 3])
Coordinates:
  * cd       (cd) MultiIndex
  - c        (cd) object 'a' 'b' 'c'
  - d        (cd) object 'a' 'b' 'c'
Dimensions without coordinates: multi_index

In [13]: d.set_index(cd=['c', 'd']).sel(c='b')
Out[13]: 
<xarray.DataArray (multi_index: 3)>
array([1, 2, 3])
Coordinates:
  * d        (d) object 'b'
Dimensions without coordinates: multi_index
```

However, vectorized selection is not yet supported for MultiIndex,
(it will complain `ValueError: Vectorized selection is not available along level variable`)

Maybe the first option is better for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!
To recover the original MultiIndex structure, I could then do `d.swap_dims({'multi_index': 'c'}).sel(c=['a', 'b']).stack(multi_index=['c'])`. This then also allows for (iterative) selection of multiple levels.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works when `multi_index` is defined as a dimension without variables. When it is stacked (e.g. `d = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3], coords={'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd': ('c', ['x', 'y', 'z'])}, dims=['c']).stack(multi_index=['c'])`), `d.swap_dims({'multi_index': 'c'})` complains with a `KeyError: 'c'`.

Comment: Yes, `swap_dims` swaps 'dimension' and 'non-dimensional coordinate' but not levels in MultiIndex. I think before doing 'swap_dims', you may need to unstack it by `.unstack('multi_index')`